# Entering into the database if request input is not null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to enter into my pictures table when my input file has something inside it only, so not null. unfortunately the code i have tried doesn't seem to upload into the database when the input is not null. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
    if(!empty($request->input('image'))){
        $picture = new Picture();
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = uniqid('img_') . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
            Image::make($image)->save($location);
            $picture->image = $filename;
        }
        $picture->user_id = $request->user()->id;
        $picture->save();

    }else {

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $picture = new Picture();

    $image = $request->file('image');
    $filename = uniqid('img_') . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
    Image::make($image)->save($location);
    $picture->image = $filename;

    $picture->user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $picture->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open database and open table then after this field default null set for image

Me working fine try you.